# How to start Game Developing?

Tags: c++, programming-languages

i'm someone who is very interested in games and want to be able to make them myself. I researched some things and i've started learning c++ because i thought that would be the best language to go with...

Now like i said i've started learning c++ and by that i mean i'm reading at this point this book :
-Beginning c++ through Game Programming Third Edition- but my question to you guys is, what books should i read next to be able to make games, i mean the normal c++ books (if the knowledge i have from this book , what it probarly is, isn't enought) and game developement books?

Yes i know there has been a simular question : [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) but i ask something different, these books are good for the basic c++ but i want books wich can guide me to be a game developer...

Comment: if this is the first language your learning c++ isn't a great idea, that being said you should ask this question on [game dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I highly recommend SFML Game Development, using SFML C++ media library. It requires a foundation knowledge of C++ so it shouldn't be your first book, but an excellent second or third.

Comment: See also the famous [C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the best ways to learn about game development is to jump straight into a game engine. One good game engine is Unreal Engine 3. It's free for non-commercial use and there's countless resources and tutorials.

Take a look at these links:

http://www.unrealengine.com/udk/

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn/how-to-learn-udk-the-unreal-development-kit/

Comment: yes but what if i want to make a game commercial.. i mean yes it's good for the starting but i need my resources where i can build on if i ever want to make a commercial game... so if you know any good books please say it (ps: i'm considering the book -Game Coding Complete: Fourth edition- is it a good choice? )